# How do I get the pid of the exact progarm launched

Tags: terminal, process, python, console

So I have a couple python programs say program A and program B, when using "pgrep python" to get the pid, it gives me the pid of both program A and program B. However, I am writing a program that need to find the pid of program B, but not program A. My plan is to have the program run a console comamand, "pgrep" to get the pid. However, since it gets both pids, and it can't tell the difference between the two (that I know off)

So how can I ensure I get the pid of Program B but not program A?

Comment: Is there anything unique about the programs names?  How would you tell them apart?  You can use the `-f` flag to `pgrep` to look at the full command line (including parameters) so perhaps that would help?

Answer (score 2):

One option is that the process that launches Program B can retrieve the PID after doing so and save it in a file somewhere (e.g., `/var/run/` often contains such `X.pid` files). One way to do this is to launch Program B from a script into the background, and then inspect the shell variable `$!`, like so:

```
ProgramB &
B_PID=$!
```

Often with this strategy, the `X.pid` file can get stale---that is, the launched process may die without the `X.pid` file being removed, and that PID may even get recycled for some other process. If the Program B hasn't been launched in the meantime, the `X.pid` file won't have been updated, so you'd have to check both that a process with the PID stored in the `X.pid` file exists, and also that that process has the command name you're expecting.

Another strategy is to inspect the arguments that Program B is reported as having been launched with. You can get `ps` or `pgrep` to give you that information. As a commentor says, the flag to use for `pgrep` is `-f`.